# SQL to fetch value of one column such that a certain value in another column does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following Table t

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | c |

In the above table, the Key 1 has three values i.e. a, b and c. However Key 2 has only two values i.e. a and c.

How to write a SQL that would return the Key that does NOT have the value 'b'? In the above example the SQL must return the Key 2

Comment: A query returns "rows". What is the content of the rows that you wish to retrieve?

Comment: The query must return the content 2. I dont want to retrieve the entire row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this by creating a counter for b values per key and then selecting only the keys with 0 b values:

```
SELECT 
   key
FROM (SELECT
         t.key, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.value = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_b_values
      FROM t
      GROUP BY t.key)
WHERE number_of_b_values = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
with b_keys as
(
    select distinct key
    from t
    where value = 'b'
)

select distinct key
from t
left join b_keys
  on t.key = b_keys.key
where b_keys.key is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you really looking explicitely for "b"?

Or do you actually need to find whatever keys are missing - ie - it might not be "b" but "a" or "c" that was missing?

If you build a list of all *expected* values you can then use it with a *not exists* to identify all keys that are missing any values:

```
with v as (
    select distinct t.[key], dv.[value]
    from (select distinct [value] from t) dv
    cross join t
)
select [key]
from v
where not exists (select * from t where t.[value] = v.[value] and t.[key] = v.[key]);
```

[See Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d4b5c17f20c7aa783b3f5cf8026e2af6)